# setup Identityserver3 for SSO

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I have 3 MVC applications each of which uses a different DB to keep the users handled by Asp.Net Identity. These applications sometimes call some web APIs through Ajax calls. I need to provide the SSO functionality using IdentityServer3 so that one of my MVC applications sever as the Identity Server and therefore if the users want to access any of these 3 applications, they just go (or be redirected to) the Login view of the main application and be authenticated using Asp.Net Identity. I have been trying for more than a week to make the samples provided on Internet to fit into my situation but so far no success. If someone could just give me the guideline it would be great cause I totally fill lost.

**Note:** It would be ideal if I could have a dedicated identity server manipulated by the ASP.Net Identity (for roles, ...).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of example apps provided that do pretty much everything you require. Check out [IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples)

The two applications that directly apply to you are the **AspNetIdentiy** and the **MVC** samples.

You should really prepare yourself and set expectations for you boss that you are going to need a few days to study and understand Identity Server. A lot of people seem to have impression that Identity Server is an application that you just install, configure and use, but it is closer to a application framework than an application. The examples and the documentation is more than sufficient though if you apply yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was already studying these samples and as you said it takes time and is closer to a framework. I will share the result in the end or maybe I create a step by step solution for people who want to use it easily.